# Nested select in create table query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to write create table statement with query with nested select in if construction to compare with number constant. So that the code is readable.

```
create table transaction_client stored
    as
select
    if(c.record_id = '01',
       'Handle',
       c.record_name) as type,
    if(c.record_id = '02',
       cast(t.amount as string),
       '')            as value,
    if(c.record_id = '02',
       c.record_name,
       '')            as attribute
from transaction  t
join       client c
           on c.id = t.client_id;
```

I tried to use the with structure and select code from table, but it does not allow the use of different values in rows.

```
create table classifier as
select
    stack(5,
          '01', 'CODE_01', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE',
          '02', 'CODE_02', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE',
          '03', 'CODE_03', 'TRANSACTION_TYPE'
        ) as (code, description, classifier_name)
from any_table;

create table transaction_client stored
    as orc as
with
    cl as (select code as code from classifier where classifier_name = 'TRANSACTION_TYPE' and description = 'CODE_01')
select
    if(c.record_id = cl.code,
       'Handle',
       c.record_name) as type,
    if(c.record_id = cl.code,
       cast(t.amount as string),
       '')            as value,
    if(c.record_id = cl.code,
       c.record_name,
       '')            as attribute
from transaction  t
join       client c
           on c.id = t.client_id
cross join t;
```

I also tried using a map, but the query execution speed is doubled.

```
set hivevar:classifier=map('01', 'CODE_01',
                           '02', 'CODE_02', 
                           '03', 'CODE_03')

....
 if(c.record_id = ${classifier}['CODE_01'],
       'Handle',
       c.record_name) as type,
...
```

Please tell me which structure is better to avoid magic number and make code more readable?

Comment: To me your first code example is much more readable, understandable and you said it performs better. Why bother about magic numbers at all. Add comments and move on. You can also replace all magic numbers with variables (each). No maps. This will be even better.